# How to add gridview controls dynamically when retrieve values from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to retrieve values and bind it in gridview from database

Based on the row count I want to add the controls dynamically

**Code:**

In my table I have 2 rows but using the below code I can get only 2nd row value

```
protected void Gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select activities,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday from activity_values where week = '" + weekNumNow + "' and emp_id = (select emp_id from emp_master where username = '" + username + "')", DbConnection);
    // DbConnection.Open();
    OleDbDataReader dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr1.Read())
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //find the control
            DropDownList drop1 = e.Row.FindControl("dropActivities") as DropDownList;
            TextBox box1 = e.Row.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
            TextBox box2 = e.Row.FindControl("TextBox2") as TextBox;
            TextBox box3 = e.Row.FindControl("TextBox3") as TextBox;
            TextBox box4 = e.Row.FindControl("TextBox4") as TextBox;
            TextBox box5 = e.Row.FindControl("TextBox5") as TextBox;
            TextBox box6 = e.Row.FindControl("TextBox6") as TextBox;
            TextBox box7 = e.Row.FindControl("TextBox7") as TextBox;

            drop1.Text = dr1[0].ToString();
            box1.Text = dr1[1].ToString();
            box2.Text = dr1[2].ToString();
            box3.Text = dr1[3].ToString();
            box4.Text = dr1[4].ToString();
            box5.Text = dr1[5].ToString();
            box6.Text = dr1[6].ToString();
            box7.Text = dr1[7].ToString();
        }
        rowIndex++;
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> I want to retrieve values and bind it in gridview from database

You can fill data from your repository/DAL & databind your gridview inside page Load event. You don't have to use row DataBound event at all as this would open a database connection for every row rendered.I think you are seeing just one row because its the last row returned by database. Some pseudo code

```
PageLoad()
{
   if(!Page.IsPostBack)
   { 
     PopulateMyGrid();
   }
}

private void PopulateMyGrid()
{
    DataTable myDataTable=null;
    // Your DAL code goes here (you can fill the datatable from your database)
    myGrid.DataSource = myDatatable;
    myGrid.DataBind();
}
```

You can add template fields inside your gridview for your textboxes. For each textbox your would specify the name of your dataTable column so it gets databind automatically.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" runat="sever" Text='<%#Bind("YourDataTableColumnName") %>' ></asp:TextBox>   
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response..I know this code should work fine but if I don't have any values in database table then here Text='<%#Bind("YourDataTableColumnName") %> we will get an error right? then how to fix it?

Comment: @user2500094 You would not get any error. What have you tried?

Comment: See this link http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/08/02/save-dynamic-textbox-values-from-gridview-to-database.aspx I implement this and I want to read that values thru the same gridview thru which we have added

Comment: Please help me how to retrieve that values?